# How to redirect iFrame after third part form submit?

Tags: iframe, redirect, submit

I have a third party form that I can't control. I'm putting that form on my webpage via an iFrame. I am then trying to redirect that iFrame to a new page after the form has been submitted.

Example:
User visits my webpage. They enter their email in the web-form. They then hit submit. The iFrame is redirected to a page that displays "Thanks for confirming your email!" etc..

Essentially after they enter their email I want that iFrame to redirect to a different page. I don't know how to do it because I don't control the form. I was thinking maybe adding a button or function when they hit enter or click submit that it submits the form then after a set amount of time it r

Answer (score 0):

This is considered cross site scripting http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting so I'm not sure if it will work. Maybe you could open the subscribe form in a modal(like this http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/) and then the user will close the modal when he wants.